# How to center table in box in Shiny Dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinydashboard

I'm having difficulty centering a table I made in Shiny Dashboard within a box. I used a .csv file, but here is some fake data:

```
Stage = c("Survey", "Work Sample", "Interview", "Stats Test")
Score = c("+33.7%", "+14.8%", "+20.8%", "+28.17%")
no1_cand = data.frame(Stage, Score)
Score =c("+37.1%", "+14.2%", "+19.3%", "+26.3%")
no2_cand = data.frame(Stage, Score)
Score = c("+33.1%", "+22.2%", "+17.3%", "+25.8%")
no3_cand = data.frame(Stage, Score)
Score = c("+29.1%", "+17.2%", "+15.3%", "+23.3%")
no4_cand = data.frame(Stage, Score)
Score = c("+22.1%", "+12.5%", "+11.4%", "+19.5%")
no5_cand = data.frame(Stage, Score)
```

and the current code I have for the table and box:

```
#UI
    box(title = "Top 5 Candidates",
                      status = "primary",
                      solidHeader = F,
                      collapsible = T,
                      width = 12,
                      fluidRow(
                        tableOutput('top5')))
#Server
  output$top5 = renderTable({
    top5_data
  })
```

Currently it looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
box(title = "Top 5 Candidates"
, status = "primary", solidHeader = F
, collapsible = T, width = 12
, column(12, align="center", tableOutput('top5')))
```